# IE9 RC1 incorrectly encoding input field names that have character entities

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I think I may have found a bug with the latest IE9 release candidate, but before I log the issue on connect.microsoft.com, I wanted to validate with the brains-trust here that my understanding is correct.

**Problem:**

A HTML form contains an input field, whose name attribute contains character entities (&quot),  eg. <input type="text" name="MyText[Identifier=&quot;test&quot;]" value="hello">

In IE8, FF, Safari & Chrome, when the form is submitted, any non-safe ASCII chars are encoded in the HTTP request.  So the above input field would be sent in the POST as

MyText%5BIdentifier%3D%22test%22%5D=hello

Here, we can see that the square brackets are encoded as %5B and %5D, the equals symbol is encoded as %3D, and the &quot entities encoded as %22.

In IE9 RC1, this input field is being sent in the POST as

MyText%5BIdentifier%3D% **25** 22test% **25** 22%5D=hello

> What *seems* to have happened here is,
>   after the non-safe ASCII chars are
>   encoded, IE9 is then *further
>   encoding* the percent symbols of the
>   %22 as %25 (giving %2522).

I don't think it should be doing this (and as I mentioned above, no other browsers, including previous IE versions, did this).

According to the W3C validator, character entities such as &quot in input names are valid, so it's not simply a case of IE9 being stricter than the other browsers, as I first thought.

Is my assumption correct, and should I proceed to log this as a bug in IE9?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the exact same issue. Got around it by replacing the nested double quotes with single quotes.